# Storage Access Framework - failing to obtain document tree from uri (returned from Drive app)

Tags: java, android, uri, directory-structure, storage-access-framework

My Android app wants to create a folder in Google Drive and get the uri from the Drive app on the device.

It sends an intent, you can see the code below:

```
private void createFolder(String folderName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    // Create a file with the requested MIME type.
    intent.setType("vnd.android.document/directory");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, folderName);
    startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

then it gets the returned data, you can see the code below:

```
@Override
protected void  onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData)
{

    if (requestCode == WRITE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Uri uri = null;
       if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            Log.i("result", "Uri: " + uri.toString());
            DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri); //this line gives the error
                       }
    }

}
```

I used a mimetype found on the internet that seems to be a standard type. The same error is issued when using "application/vnd.google-apps.folder".
The goal is to have a document tree but in logcat I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=43, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc=1;doc=encoded=LongStringWithRandomCharactersHere/j flg=0x43 }} to activity {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3DSameLongStringWithRandomCharactersHere%2Fj
```

and below

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3DAnotherLongStringWithDifferentRandomDataHere
```

Here's the complete stack trace:

```
2019-05-31 15:06:50.167 31184-31184/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 31184
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=43, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc=1;doc=encoded=randomcharacters flg=0x43 }} to activity {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3Drandomcharacters
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4365)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4409)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1670)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3Drandomcharacters
    at android.provider.DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(DocumentsContract.java:1023)
    at android.support.v4.provider.DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(DocumentFile.java:138)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:254)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7295)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4361)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4409) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1670) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6687) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

The uri is not wrong because I can further extract the name of the folder (and the size=0), that is successfully created on the Drive cloud.
What's wrong instead? It seems that my app cannot handle it as a document tree.

Comment: "What's wrong instead?" -- `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` is for creating documents, not trees. There is no requirement for any `DocumentsProvider` to honor that MIME type in the way that you are expecting. "It seems that my app cannot handle it as a document tree" -- the Storage Access Framework presumably is treating it as a document, since that is what you asked to create via `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: @CommonsWare "document" is also a folder in the SAF jargon, in fact, a document can have other documents under its level. At least the Drive app is happy with or tolerates it because I see the folder is created.

Comment: That does not mean that the Storage Access Framework middleware is going to work the way that you think it will.

Comment: @CommonsWare OK, but what action is intended (sorry for the wordplay) to be requested, for the middleware to be happy?

Comment: There is no `Intent` action to create a tree that I know of. AFAIK, the expected approach is to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to choose the parent, then use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` and [`createDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile?hl=en#createDirectory(java.lang.String)) to create the new tree.

Comment: @CommonsWare If I use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Android says that no app is capable of handling the intent (Drive won't open), so I think it is not implemented (I have other cloud apps on the device, and they won't come up too, even with createChooser option)

Comment: I have great difficulty believing that error message, at least on Android 5.1+, since you can create trees on device storage. It is certainly possible that Drive does not support creating trees, as a `DocumentsProvider` can indicate if it supports that operation.

Comment: @CommonsWare Why doesn't the chooser show up? and the same question is for the filesystem root chooser, if you are right about document trees being created on the device

Comment: You might post a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] showing what you are trying for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. I have never had a problem with it showing up, and I have never had a problem creating trees on device storage. Personally, I'm not a Drive user, so I haven't been checking to see whether Drive is an available option.

Comment: @CommonsWare so "java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result" says nothing to you? Cannot fix the original code in the post? Drive works but just the handling of the returned intent by may app is not working

Comment: "Drive works but just the handling of the returned intent by may app is not working" -- I am not surprised. It was an interesting hack, but even if you got it working now, I would not assume that it would work across all current and future Drive versions and all current and future SAF versions (including manufacturer "tweaks").

Comment: @CommonsWare I do not want to bother you but, as I said, a document tree is from a document, IMHO, so it is not a hack, I think that understanding what the error means could give some information about whether in the future Drive could create the folder correctly or not

Comment: "so it is not a hack" -- you are assuming that because a MIME type appears in `DocumentContract` that it is a valid MIME type for `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`. I think that assumption is invalid. "I think that understanding what the error means could give some information about whether in the future Drive could create the folder correctly or not" -- then examine the source code. You did not provide a complete stack trace, so I cannot tell you exactly what is throwing that exception, but go look there and see what the criteria are for a `Uri` being deemed invalid.

Comment: @CommonsWare the uri is not invalid because with further instructions I can get the name of the created folder (and size=0). I edited the question adding the stack trace

Comment: It would appear that you created an ordinary document, not a tree, from the standpoint of the SAF middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working with Google Drive cloud space but maybe it's a hack. It is not guaranteed to always work.

This example creates a cloud file in a cloud folder that was created by the user (the SAF picker is opened by the app).

Creating the cloud folder (the user has to select the cloud root first from the picker UI)

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
 intent.setType("vnd.android.document/directory");
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
 startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CREATE_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_CODE) 
    {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      int takeFlags = data.getFlags()
                   &
      (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      ContentResolver resolver = this.getContentResolver();
      resolver.takePersistableUriPermission(data.getData(),takeFlags);
      archiveUri(data.getData().toString()); //important to save the toString() result, not getPath()
      archiveAuthority(data.getData().getAuthority());
      } 
      else 
      {
            // The user cancelled the request.
      }
    }
}
```

using the Uri next time

```
ContentResolver contentResolver;
contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
uriPath=retrieveArchivedUri();
Uri tempUri;
Uri uri; 
String authority;
tempUri=Uri.parse(uriPath);
authority=retrieveArchivedAuthority();
uri= DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri(authority,
            DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(tempUri)); //folder Uri

try 
{
 DocumentsContract.createDocument(contentResolver,uri,"plain/text","fileName");
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @CommonsWare maybe you are interested in seeing this

Comment: This is interesting. But how do you write to this file after it is created? I seem to get permission denied errors

Comment: @m33ts4k0z Do you mean you tried my code and it did not work, or you think it gives an error?
The flags are very important, the problem was mainly with the intent. However that was a hack and as I could see by now the SAF middleware does not like it or there is a bug (because in theory the action of the intent is logically coherent),

Comment: Your code works, it creates an empty file. But how to append to that file?

Comment: I tried to write to the file created using the resulting URI like that but I get permission denial: 
var new_file = DocumentsContract.createDocument(contentResolver,uri,"plain/text","fileName");
  contentresolve.openFileDescriptor(new_file, "w")?.use {
                val pathToNewFile = FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor)
            val inFile = context.openFileInput(file).readBytes()
            context.openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
                pathToNewFile.write(inFile)
            }
            File(absolutePath + File.separator + file).delete()
        }

Comment: @m33ts4k0z Please ask a question and when it is opened poke me here.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56965828/how-to-append-to-a-created-file-using-its-uri