# Storage Access Framework - How to append to a created file using its URI?

Tags: android, kotlin, storage-access-framework

Using the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56633238/2196870) post, I was able to use OPEN_CREATE_DOCUMENT as a folder picker in order for GDrive to appear in the list. The code in that answer creates an empty file. Now, I'm trying to append/write to that file. I tried using DocumentFile and openFileDescriptor. Both of them are failing. The latter with a permission denial exception saying that I need to add MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or 
 use uripermission(). We cant use MANAGE_DOCUMENTS in the manifest since its a system permission and I haven't found a way to use the uripermission(). Here is the code:

```
 var new_file = DocumentsContract.createDocument(context.contentResolver ,path,"audio/mp3",file)

 contentresolve.openFileDescriptor(new_file, "w")?.use {
                val pathToNewFile = FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor)
            val inFile = context.openFileInput(file).readBytes()
            context.openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
                pathToNewFile.write(inFile)
            }
            File(absolutePath + File.separator + file).delete()
        }
```

This is the intent:

```
folderPicker = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
folderPicker.addFlags(
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
       or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
       or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
       )
folderPicker.setType("vnd.android.document/directory")
startActivityForResult(folderPicker, READ_REQUEST_BY_USER)
```

And this is the activity result:

```
            override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, resultData: Intent?) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData)
            if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_BY_USER && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                resultData?.data?.also { uri ->
                    val takeFlags: Int = folderPicker.flags and (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                    activity!!.contentResolver!!.persistedUriPermissions.forEach {
                        activity!!.contentResolver!!.releasePersistableUriPermission(it.uri, takeFlags)
                    }
                    activity!!.contentResolver!!.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)
                    val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity?.baseContext)
                    with (sharedPref.edit()) {
                        putString("savePathURI", uri.toString())
                        putString("saveAuthority", uri.authority)
                        commit()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: As you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56931484/storage-access-provider-creation-of-folder-in-authorized-directory-fails I encountered a similar problem. According to CommonsWare it is because of the "wrong" intent action, although I think that it is SAF's fault and there is a bug. This is going to be fixed because some feature requests have been filed about this kind of issues by me and CommonsWare. Check my last questions.

Comment: So in other words, creating an empty file is as far as we can get with your "hack"? We can't actually use your solution to create files, right?

Comment: @P5music Just noticed that just yesterday, the issue you created on google tracker was acknowledged as a defect and was forwarded for a fix. That is great actually. It means it will be fixed.

Comment: Still we have to expect issues and bugs for some time to come, I do not think all is due to the wrong intent action. I think SAF is not fully functional at present time, but it is going to be in the next future because its use will be mandatory as far as I understood. Even if it will not end up being mandatory it is very powerful and we want to use it, so our requests will be listened.

Comment: But there is no other API in order to gain access to external storage right? We need to use SAF in order to be able to i.e. write in a subfolder in the SD card.

Comment: At present time you can, with suitable permissions in the manifest, using the File class and similar, but not in the future if SAF will be mandatory and no opting-out permissions for legacy apps on newest Android versions will be allowed.

Comment: I want also point out that it is not unlikely that the errors are mutating, because it's the server that answers with different responses, they maybe change something because they realized that accesses are attempted. So what I got with my early attempts could not be relevant anymore now.

Comment: This is the exception that I get when I try to write to the file. Creating the file works without errors: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.google.android.apps.docs.storagebackend.StorageBackendContentProvider uri content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3Dj5Pyf60pC5BDC3FJk6CGSyRkhpNEse5KHh0TOI3xZ6WXB1tLrTSdf8PoN5ir from pid=12449, uid=10343 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: Yes, I think it's some new response from the server that causes the middleware react in a different way than before.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56931484/storage-access-provider-creation-of-folder-in-authorized-directory-fails

Comment: @P5music This is how I solved it for now. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this can take forever to get fixed, I ended up using Google Drive's REST API v3 in order to meet my needs. I added another entry in my app's menu inviting the user to choose a google drive path.

I created a new activity with a recyclerview which fetches all folders. I then added a button under each folder which allows the user to choose it as his/hers desired folder. I then save the folder ID in the sharedprefences on button click.

When the time comes to upload the file, I create a new API create() request and I use the saved folder id as the parent of the soon to be uploaded file.

Works pretty well but I didn't like the fact that I needed a second entry in the settings and that I needed 3 days to code all this from scratch.

Comment: I avoid using that kind of APIs because in a few years I should have to rewrite my app because the deprecation of the API. If they can deprecate the File class on locations outside the internal app folders, they can do anything I fear, so better to depend on APIs less possible, for my part

Comment: @P5music yeah but actually we dont have a choice since google has deprecated GDAA and there is no other way to save files to drive directly.

Comment: I do not understand very well what your app does, but for now applications still can use the normal functions, mine included, the change will happen in next year as far as I know

Comment: Yes it happens in december 2019

Comment: @P5music here is the roadmap: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation

Comment: we are talking about different deprecations, a more drastic deprecation will be about the use of File class outside the private app folder https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/05/storage-access-framework-counterpoints.html